# Continuous Integration and environments used for various test suites

Tags: automation, continuous-integration

As part of CI process do you run unit tests on different environments from where the functional end to end system tests are run by QA or use the same environment. I feel that different env are required as using 1 environment will basically be a bit risky as if unit tests failed because of latest merge and commits and break the critical functionality that could affect existing QA efforts as environments are same. But if team uses different environments then failure of units tests do not affect QA as they continue to test as they have a different environment.

Would like to know if the above is being followed or not or if any better process someone follows please share.

Some teams object to haveing 2 different envs for unit and functional QA tests as overhead to deployment but I disagree. 
All suggestions feedback appreciated here with examples of currently followed processes in your projects.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should clarify what do you mean by environments. OS-es and/or tools used to build/test the sw? Branches in the sw version control system(s)? Real hw vs emulated/virtual hw?

Answer (score 0):

The functionality should work regardless of the environment

> having 2 different envs for unit and functional QA tests as overhead to deployment

This is no longer and issue with modern tools support (like [Octopus Deploy](https://octopus.com/)), those tasks can be chained on successful build in any serious [CI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) server. Basically there is no practical limitation how [many versions](http://www.infoq.com/news/2014/03/etsy-deploy-50-times-a-day) you can push up to Prod daily.

Dividing your Test envs will give you a [faster feedback](http://blogs.agilefaqs.com/2014/10/03/key-principles-for-reducing-continuous-integration-build-time/), unit tests run faster than than UI ones.

In my experience we had (at least these)

- Dev env - for Unit tests, where you can build and run those multiple times a day.
- Int env - for Integration tests, where different services/modules were tested once they are stable enough.
- QA env - for System tests, where all UAT and E2E tests prove that this release candidate is [MVP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_viable_product) and ready for Prod.